# Automatic argument type deduction with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am currently writing a C++ <-> python wrapper using `boost::python`. In c++, I am using `Eigen` for numerical computation, while I use `numpy` in python. To be able to easily make wrappers for my C++ code I want to apply a transformation to each argument (for example casting from a python type to a C++ type), and then call the corresponding function.

Suppose the C++ method and the transformations are all structs with the static method ´call´, i.e., simplified

```
struct cppFunction {
    static double call(double a) { return a * 10; }
};

struct T1 {
    static double call(int a) { return static_cast<double>(a); }
};
```

I then want to be able to do define a function that i can pass to `boost::python`

```
auto wrappedFunction = &wrap<CppFunction, T1>>
```

To do this, I need to automatically deduce the input arguments of `CppFunction`, I can do this with traits:

```
template <class F> struct ArgType;

template <class R, class T>
struct ArgType<R (*)(T)> {
    typedef T argument_type;
};
```

With only 1 argument this can be implemented as:

```
template <typename Function, typename T1>
auto wrap(typename ArgType<decltype(&T1::call)>::argument_type a1)
-> decltype(Function::call(T1::call(a1))) {
        return Function::call(T1::call(a1));
    }
};
```

However, in the general case with a variadic number of inputs, it's natural to write:

```
struct cppFunction {
    static double call(double a, double b, double c) { return a * b * c; }
};

template <typename Function, typename... T>
auto wrap(typename ArgType<decltype(&T::call)>::argument_type... args)
     -> decltype(Function::call(T::call(args)...))       {
    return Function::call(T::call(args)...);
}

auto wrappedFunction = &wrap<CppFunction, T1, T1, T1>>
```

This however fails on my compiler (VS2013), complaining that

> ArgType::argument_type does not contain a parameter pack

Is there any canonical way to implement what I am trying to do here?

Comment: your `wrap` in the last case seems a bit wrong, where is `args` appearing in the template list?

Comment: thank you, a1 should be args, fixing that. The error still remains though.

Comment: Seems fine to me after correcting typos, and gcc compiles OK: http://goo.gl/BSdWcT VS2013 is known to have issues with variadics.

Comment: Thank you for the information @ecatmur! It does indeed seem like a compiler bug then.